# ReactJS, Formik - validate field, compare value to another

Tags: reactjs, parent, formik, ref

What would be the correct syntax to validate one field, by comparing its value to another fields' value? I'm using a Formik form with a rather nested structure and I've prepared a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-swanson-kbu9p?file=/src/FormFields.js).

I was trying with adding a forwardRef to child component and then trying to retreive it via useRef() in parent, but I keep getting the ref.current as undefined, when trying to focus it inside the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the value of a field to another one, you can achieve that by using `yup.ref()` from yup validation schema.
For example, to check if `email_address_1` is different from `email_address_2` you can do something like this:

```
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email_address_1: yup.string().email().required(),
  email_address_2: yup.string().email()
    .optional().notOneOf([yup.ref("email_address_1")], "Must be a different email")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `validate` function (to your `useFormik` function as an argument or to your `Formik` component as a prop) and implement it like so:

```
export default function validate(values) {

    const errors = {};

    if (values.field1 !== values.field2) {
        errors.field2 = 'field1 must match field2';
    }
    return errors;
};
```